# Differential geometry of Limaçons

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, rt.representation-theory

While reading up on [Limaçons](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Limacon.html) I learned they are the envelope of one circle around another.

> The limaçon can be generated by specifying a fixed point P, then
>   drawing a sequences of circles with centers on a given circle C which
>   all pass through P. The envelope of these curves is a limaçon. If the
>   fixed point is on the circumference of the circle, then the envelope
>   is a cardioid.

In fact, I even [drew](http://jsfiddle.net/mrcactu5/fRgtF/) the foliation myself, exploring how the circles change as you move the fixed point P.

[image] <sup>[(source)](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/images/eps-gif/LimaconEnvelope_800.gif)</sup>

I gather that [envelopes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Envelope_(mathematics)) are often [1-parameter families of solutions to differential equations](http://www.mif.pg.gda.pl/kfal/sft/Cohen_1911.pdf).  This is related to an old-fashioned way of defining Lie Groups as symmetries of differential equations.

We can directly compute the function $f:(P, \theta)\mapsto (x,y,r)$ taking each point $P$ in the plane and angle $\theta$  (relative to the vertical) on the circle C.

What is the map here?  What is that differential equation here?

Huygens principle may be involved here, so can this foliation be studied with [contact geometry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contact_geometry)?

Comment: feel free to move to math.StackExchange if necessary.

Comment: what is $(x,y,r)$?

Comment: Instead of «foliation», I'd use the term «web», since locally the structure of the picture is that of the superposition of $2$ foliations. You may have some luck with that keyword, especially regarding webs related to the study of  caustics.

Comment: If $P$ is fixed then it is still just a one parameter family of curves, hence locally a foliation. But I still don't understand the actual question.